# How to deal with my collegue with bad smell?

Tags: work-environment, colleagues

A new employee joined us before a week and was seated beside me,but I cannot able to bear with him as he smells fishy everyday right from the start and gets worse at end of the day.

Now how can I come across this co-worker how to make him realise this thing ad this thing making me sick and cannot able to concentrate on my work.I asked for my office boy to put some room freshener but that only helps for sometime.

Comment: There are other questions with this general topic. Basically, your coworker may not be aware that he smells and may be humiliated if the issue is brought up. You'll have to tell him, directly face-to-face, but in a really polite and discreet way. This is not something management can handle well, no need to bring anyone else into this problem unless he ignores your suggestion.

Comment: This sort of thing isn't always about personal hygiene.

Answer (score -1):

Go to you manager.

Tell your manager how it is affecting your job and make it their problem not yours, they have the power to solve it.

This is about your well-being and you should have little tolerance about situations negatively impacting your performance.
If there are such situations, your manager needs to know.